# Catching an exception when instantiating a class field

Tags: java

I want to instantiate a URL as a private field in a class, but I can't catch the MalformedURLException.  I've tried using a static initialization block, but that doesn't work either.  How do I solve this?

```
public class MyClass{ 

    private final static URL DEFAULT_URL = new URL("http://www.yadayada.com?wsdl")

    ...
}
```

Comment: Whre do you instantiate MyClass? Can't you catch the exception there?

Comment: Why didnt the static initializer work?

Comment: Why does it have to be a static field?

Comment: It's a wrapper class for a webservice client.  The private fields(including this one) are the default values that can be overridden/configured by a properties file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple workaround is to create a static method:

```
private final static URL DEFAULT_URL = getDefaultUrl();

private static URL getDefaultUrl() {
    try {
        return new URL("http://www.yadayada.com?wsdl"); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //what do you want to do here?
        return null; //that is an option
        throw new AssertionError("Invalid URL"); //that is another one
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Although returning null is questionable - Tom's proposal to throw an unchecked exception is better. I have added that.

Comment: Up to the specific use case; both are legitimate. There's something wrong with a nullary method throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, though :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Haha - indeed :-) Fixed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Is there any consequence to throwing an exception from a static context (it is static here, right?). Will an exception affect the class being loaded correctly?

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes, the class *initialization* (not *loading*) will fail with the exception. The stacktrace will show it as a `<clinit>` method.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to throw something in the case of an exception. An `Error` should do the job.

```
public class MyClass{ 

    private static final URL DEFAULT_URL;
    static {
        try {
            DEFAULT_URL = new URL("http://www.yadayada.com?wsdl")
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException exc) {
            throw new Error(exc);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In case an exception is thrown (it shouldn't be) the class will fail to initialse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the static block

```
public class MyClass { 

    private final static URL DEFAULT_URL; 

    static {
      try {
       DEFAULT_URL = new URL("http://www.yadayada.com?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using static block initializer - you may catch exception inside the block.

However, I would not recommend to store it as final class field as URI. Place it as String constant and initialize in constructor or special `init()` intance method

Answer (score 0):

Try below. you cannot use final keyword for below:

```
private static URL DEFAULT_URL = null;
    static{
        try {
            DEFAULT_URL = new URL("http://www.yadayada.com?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```